# How to split comma separated integer string in MYSQL with in the select clause?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

How to achieve REGEXP_SUBSTR in MYSQL with select clause, without using temp table and store procedure. Can any one give a solution for this please. (Mysql Version 5.7)
Below query is in Oracle, I want same as in MYSQL
EX:

```
SELECT *
FROM   SAMPLE
WHERE  SAMPLE_NAME IN (SELECT     REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS TEMP
                       FROM       DUAL
                       CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL);
```

Required O/P of sub Query as below :

```
TEMP | 
-----|
 1   | 
 2   | 
 3   | 
 4   | 
-----
```